# How to record a successful Google+ share

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-plus

I have a google+ share link that someone can click to share (on their own stream) a url specified by the rails app (not the current page).

I want to be able to record if the link was clicked and successfully shared. Here is the google+ share link code I'm using

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=#{@user.website}" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
  '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;"><img
  src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>
```

I know it can be done with the Twitter api:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
  twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
    $.post('<%="#{record_twitter_share_path}"%>');
  });
});
</script>
```

But is there a way to do it with Google+

Answer (score 1):

You cannot confirm if someone shared a post to their stream using the Share widget parameters or the JavaScript API. Niraj's answer is flawed and does not work, see [this JSBin to try it](http://jsbin.com/EhOpOba/1/edit?html,console,output).

In some situations, you can surround the widget with a div that you track the clicks on that div, but [that too doesn't work](http://jsbin.com/aVAZuHI/1/edit?html,console,output).

The one option that might work though it definitely won't work all the time given that the majority of user's on Google+ don't share most of their posts publicly is that you could use the [REST API's activities.search method](http://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search) and pass the URL that you're interested in as the search parameter, but you're not going to necessarily know that this particular user shared it, or it might be private, and depending on how popular your site is you might have to page through many pages of results possibly without luck.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to track a click on the button, but not the share itself. If you use the Google+ Web Share button, you can do something like the following:

```
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-href="https://www.webniraj.com/2013/10/02/google-api-sharing-an-interactive-post/" data-onendinteraction="trackShare" data-onclick="trackShare"></div>

<!-- Place this asynchronous JavaScript just before your </body> tag -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();

  function trackShare( jsonParam ) {
      console.log( jsonParam );
  }
</script>
```

The button has the `data-onclick="trackShare"` attribute set, which calls a JavaScript function to trigger logging.

The `console.log( jsonParam )` in the `trackShare` function will return something like:

```
{
  "id": target URL,
  "type": hover|confirm
}
```

However, in my testing, it only ever returns `type: hover`, even if it was shared successfully.